# I need to remove the ' from every row of a csv

Tags: date, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files that have the data in a format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH`,value
I can split the hours off by running

```
 with open(out_path+filename,'r+') as data_r:        
            comreader = csv.reader(data_r, delimiter=' ', quotechar='"')
            for row in comreader:
                print ','.join(row)
```

from this I get

```
'YYYY-MM-DD,HH',value
```

What I need to do is remove the (') from in front of YYYY and then after HH

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `quotechar` parameter, but wrongly:

it should read `"'"` if you want to interpret `'` as the character surrounding strings.

Other than that, you can get parts of strings easily with python's slicing abilities:

```
outstring = instring[1:-1]
```

will give you everything from the 1. (dropping the 0.) to (excluding it) the last character.